# waiting in the fixed place in the code for a touch on the screen

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch

For example in a thread (because I can't wait in main loop) I have this code :

```
-(void) game {
for (Players player in players) {
    if (player.type == IA) {        // computer plays
        answer = [player play];
    else {
         [ui showQuestion];          // user plays with the touch screen
         // here waiting for the answer touch 
         answer = ????????????????   // return from waiting after touch callback

     }
     [answersArray addObject:answer];
}
answer = [self bestAnswer : answersArray];
[ui showTheBestAnswer : answer];
```

}

Is there a solution to wait for an UI Event in a fixed code place ?
without blocking the main loop of course.

Thank you very much for your help,
jpdms

Comment: The whole construct looks awkward. Do it event based, triggered from the main loop. Just store the state and react accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, I highly recommend that you read Apple's *Concurrency Programming Guide*, included with the Xcode documentation. In general, there are much better alternatives to threads, especially in the example you provide.

However:

If the `game` method is executing on a separate thread, then the proper way to signal the thread is using `NSCondition`. Create an instance and make sure both the code above and the touch handler has access to it.

```
NSCondition *playerDidTouchCondition = [[NSCondition alloc] init];
```

In the `game` method, you wait on the condition like this:

```
[ui showQuestion];
[playerDidTouchCondition lock];
[playerDidTouchCondition wait];
[playerDidTouchCondition unlock];
// do something with answer
```

Your game thread will sleep until the condition has been signaled. In your touch handler you would do this:

```
answer = whatever the user did
[playerDidTouchCondition lock];
[playerDidTouchCondition signal]; // wake up one of the sleeping threads
[playerDidTouchCondition unlock];
```

The example code you have above really doesn't demonstrate the need for a separate thread, however. You could very easily store a `currentPlayerIndex` somewhere and proceed to the next player inside of the button handler for the answer button.

Also, you MUST ensure that any UI updates are actually happening on the main thread. I hope that your lines like `[ui showQuestion]` are queuing calls on the main thread. In Cocoa you can do this easily with something like: `[ui performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showQuestion)];`

You really, really, really should not be using a separate thread for this.